# VB.NET automatically populate DataGridView column cell with DateTime.Now

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datagridview

I have a VB.NET DataGridView that requires user input to fill Null Columns. 
I have that functioning. 
I want to have the date_time column populate with the current date/time when the other columns are not NULL. The goal being to have an accurate time attached to when the other cells were populated.

I expect that I can use a timer and monitor the cells not to be null and trigger the date/time being added but I am not sure how to code the date/time population to the cell.

Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a good start:

```
Dim dateTimColumnIndex As Integer = 1 '(example number on my part)
Private Sub CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        If (e.ColumnIndex <> dateTimColumnIndex) Then
            For z As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount -1
                 If DataGridView1.Item(z, e.RowIndex).Value Is Nothing Then
                    Return
                 End If
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(dateTimColumnIndex).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
            Next
        End if

End Sub
```

Updated won't do anything until you change value of `allDoneLoading` to `True`

```
Dim allDoneLoading As Boolean = False
Dim dateTimColumnIndex As Integer = 1 '(example number on my part)
Private Sub CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
    If allDoneLoading = True Then
        If (e.ColumnIndex <> dateTimColumnIndex) Then
            For z As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
                If DataGridView1.Item(z, e.RowIndex).Value Is Nothing Then
                    Return
                End If
                DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(dateTimColumnIndex).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Claudius, I am getting an error on execution "argument out of Range" -If you are working with a collection, be sure the index is less than the size of the collection. Stops on this line...If ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView.Item(z, e.RowIndex).Value Is Nothing Then....

Comment: fixed forgot that columns index is zero based

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but I am still having issues with this. The error I get is "Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." This is the last part of my project and I think it is ready to trial. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have 12 columns.(1-12) The columns that I want to monitor for not being null are columns 10 and 12. So, if the user has added information to columns 10 and 12 populate column 11 with the date/time. Your time is appreciated

Comment: For clarity, there will be several rows that populate to the datagridview. So,any row, my be updated at any time so, I need to check across the row and add the date/time for the full length of columns 10 and 12.

Comment: i'll get back to you later tonight

Comment: When I launch my application, there is a production line select screen. I select the production line and it calls the form where the datagridview lives. The application receives this error before the form is loaded to view.

Comment: see updated part. whenever you are ready to start using this event change value of `allDoneLoading` to `true`

Comment: Awesome! WE managed to make it work! I also had to change this line-"ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView.Item(10, e.RowIndex).Value = DateTime.Now" to have a 10 for my column 10 and eliminated the date/time formatting. Thank you again for continuing support!

Comment: Claudius, It has been working well, although twice it have "locked up" and gave me an error on the line with datetime.now in it. It message asks to check for an infinite loop. Would you happen to see anything obvious?

Comment: It may be that when the date/time was written, the e.columnIndex became 10 and it continued to try to write to itself. Added this to the code...                                                                                                       If e.ColumnIndex <> 10 Then
                            ProductionDownTimeTableDataGridView.Item(10, e.RowIndex).Value = DateTime.Now
                        End If

Comment: Good. It's been a while since i dealt with datagridview